# How to map a single location and draw one circle at a time, instead an array of locations?

Tags: database, mapping, data-visualization, p5.js

I want to map one location at a time, drawing one circle at a time, instead of the entire array of locations. Instead of drawing the entire array of locations at once, I want to cycle through each location, so that it becomes a time-lapsed animation.

I have tried:

1. timer functions;
2. key is pressed;
3. creating the ellipses within a constructor function;

   and the best I can get is all of the circles at once.

```javascript
var cities;
var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;
var clat = 0;
var clng = 0;
var zoom = 1;



function preload(){
    cities = loadStrings('shooting_data.csv');
      
}

function mercX(lng) {
      lng = radians(lng);
      var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
      var b = lng + PI;
      return a * b;
}

function mercY(lat) {
      lat = radians(lat);
      var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
      var b = tan(PI/4 + lat/2);
      var c = PI - log(b);
      return a * c;
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(1980, 1020);

} 
   
  function draw() {
      translate(width/2, height/2);
      imageMode(CENTER);
      frameRate(10);
      
      
      var x = [];
      var y = [];
      var d = [];
      
        var cx = mercX(clng);
        var cy = mercY(clat);
      
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var data = cities[i].split(/,/);
//        console.log(data);
                
        var lat = data[1];
        var lng = data[2];
        var victims = data[3];
                  
        victims = pow(5, victims);
        victims = sqrt(victims);
            
            var victimsmax = sqrt(pow(5, 5));
            var x = [mercX(lng) - cx];
            var y = [mercY(lat) - cy];
            var d = [map(victims, 1, victimsmax, 10, 100)];
            
//            for (z = 0; z < x.length; z++) {
//            console.log(d[0]);
            var shotsFired = [lat, lng, victims];
            if ( mouseIsPressed == true){ 
                
          for ( var a = 0; a < x.length; a++){
          for( var b = 0; b < y.length; b++){
          for ( var c = 0; c < d.length; c++){       
         
              
          
            fill(255, 0, 0, 1);
            stroke(255, 0, 0);
            ellipse(x[a], y[b], d[c], d[c])
          }
           if  (mouseIsPressed == false){
                 
                 noFill();
                 clear();
                         
             }
  }         
          }
        }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a new variable that tracks the index of the currently drawn circle. Then you can change that index over time (possibly every frame) to change which circle is drawn.

Try to get this working with a simpler example. Can you create an array of 3 hard-coded positions, and cycle through those?